# How to fix a squeaky stylus?

Tags: technology

I got a new stylus, the ordinary rubber type, and it is working fine, but it's squeaking (which is somewhat irritating). I'm currently using talc to stop that, but it creates quite a mess. I was thinking of trying petrolatum or wax, but I don't know if these would cause the rubber to deteriorate, and I don't want to use something that could do that (like oil). So has anyone had such issue and how did they fix it?

Comment: What is a stylus, in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the display was dirty and this caused the squeaking when in touch with the new not-worn-out stylus. Proper cleaning solved it.

(It was a touch display stylus, not a wax tablet one.)

Answer (score 0):

Put a little dab of Vaseline on the tip and rub it in. Then get those screen wipes I like to use the wet ones followed with a dry one. You don’t have to use both though, then clean your screen really well. Most likely it’s the smudge on the screen you can’t see. Like build up from face/fingers. This should work make sure the tip of stylus is not oily rub just a tiny bit in real well.